# Scala wrapping method of a parametrized class (spark-cassandra-connector)

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am writing a set of methods that extend Spark RDD's API.
I have to implement a general method for storing the RDDs, and for a start I tried to wrap spark-cassandra-connector's `saveAsCassandraTable`, without success.

Here's the "extending RDD's API" part:

```
object NewRDDFunctions {
  implicit def addStorageFunctions[T](rdd: RDD[T]):
  RDDStorageFunctions[T] = new RDDStorageFunctions(rdd)
}

class RDDStorageFunctions[T](rdd: RDD[T]) {
  def saveResultsToCassandra() {
    rdd.saveAsCassandraTable("ks_name", "table_name")    // this line produces errors!
  }
}
```

...and importing the object as: `import ...NewRDDFunctions._`.

The marked line produces following errors:

```
Error:(99, 29) could not find implicit value for parameter rwf: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory[T]
    rdd.saveAsCassandraTable("ks_name", "table_name")
                            ^

Error:(99, 29) not enough arguments for method saveAsCassandraTable: (implicit connector: com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector, implicit rwf: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory[T], implicit columnMapper: com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.ColumnMapper[T])Unit.
Unspecified value parameters rwf, columnMapper.
    rdd.saveAsCassandraTable("ks_name", "table_name")
                            ^
```

I don't get why this doesn't work since `saveAsCassandraTable` is designed to work on any RDD. Any suggestions?

---

I had similar problem with the [example](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-rdds-as-new-tables) in spark-cassandra-connector docs:

```
case class WordCount(word: String, count: Long)
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(WordCount("dog", 50), WordCount("cow", 60)))
collection.saveAsCassandraTable("test", "words_new", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

...and the solution was to move case class definition out of "main" function (but I don't really know if this applies to the mentioned problem...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`saveAsCassandraTable`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala#L82-92) needs 3 implicit parameters. The first one (`connector`) has a default value, the last two (`rwf` and `columnMapper`) are not in implicit scope in your `saveResultsToCassandra` method, as a consequence your method doesn't compile.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/5020846) on another question, if you need some more information about implicits.

Turning your `saveResultsToCassandra` into the function below should work, if you have defined your tables (`TableDef`) before.

```
def saveResultsToCassandra()(
  // implicit parameters as a separate list!
  implicit rwf: RowWriterFactory[T], 
  columnMapper: ColumnMapper[T]
) {
  rdd.saveAsCassandraTable("ks_name", "table_name")
}
```

Comment: This part of code works, but when I use my `saveResultsToCassandra` method on an RDD, it raises: `Unspecified value parameters rwf, columnMapper`. How come it does not raise any errors when I use `saveAsCassandraTable("ks_name", "table_name")` directly (omitting my wrapper)? I don't want to define any tables, since `saveAsCassandraTable` does that for me. I looked at the answer you provided, but I don't know how does it apply in my case.

Comment: I had to add extra brackets just before `(implicit rwf: RowWriterFactory[T], columnMapper: ColumnMapper[T])`, thanks!